# classification using multilayer perceptron

Tags: neural-network, classification

I want to do classification using MultiLayer Perceptron with Backprogation algorithm.

I have 5 classes and any input data belong to a single class.(no multi class)

Ex: C1 C2 C3 C4 C5

Input 1 belongs to only C2
Input 2 belongs to only C5

How should I represent the output layer for each input??

```
input layer                   Output Layer
input1             :           0 1 0 0 0
input1             :           0 0 0 0 1

or 
take only single neuron in output layer.
input layer                   Output Layer
input1             :           0.4
input1             :           1.0

if <=0.2 C1
if <=0.4 C2
if <=0.6 C3
if <=0.8 C4
if <=1.0 C5
```

Is there any other better method??

Thanks,
Atish

Answer (score 2):

You should represent your 5 classes by 5 binary outputs. This is known as 1-of-C encoding, one-hot encoding, dummy variables, indicators, ...

Then you need a [softmax activation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_activation_function#Artificial_neural_networks) in the output layer which will give you class probabilities as outputs. In addition, you should use the cross-entropy (CE) error function. Softmax+CE will give you the same gradient as identity+SSE in the output layer: `dE/da_i = y_i - t_i`. Softmax+CE has been used for up to 20,000 classes in the ImageNet dataset.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases of NN, you better configure one output node to represent one class.  :)